# Java; Txt file of single integer on each line, how can I single out each integer to use in my program?

Tags: java, arrays, text

I have a txt file, each line has a single integer. I need to make a class that singles out each one, so I can then put them in an array in a different class.

I understand that it may be weird to want each single integer but I need it this way for my program.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Do you also want the line number it was found on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `Scanner` class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

More specifically, you can use [Scanner.nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) to read into whatever data structure you want.

Example reading from system input (I will leave the exercise to you to figure out how to read from a text file):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        numberList.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would to be to use Scanner class method nextInt() which would read the integers for you.
One of the Scanner constructor takes in argument as the input stream to which you can pass the InputStream corresponding to your file that you want to read.
Below will be the code then to read all the integers:

```
    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(scanner.nextInt());
    }
```

Remember the file should only have integers in this case. I will leave upto you to create inputStream for your file!